# how to realize a serch filter with javascript

Tags: html, jquery

this filter made with jquery works only partially as it has to search for what I write only in the desc part therefore with the selector #elenco .cliente . desc but if I put this then it rightly hides only that part in the elements where the inserted text is not present, instead if I leave the selector as in the posted code it looks for the text also in the functions part but hides the whole element. So how can I make the text to be searched only in desc but then to hide the elements in full?

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sito").on("keyup", function() {
          var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
          $("#elenco .cliente ").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            console.log(this)

          });
        });
    });
```

```html
<body>
  <html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id = "header">
    
        <div id="box">
            <input id="sito" name="txt" placeholder="CLIENTE" type="text" size=15 onChange="n = 0;">
            <input type="radio" value="All" checked name="test"><label>All</label>
            <input type="radio" value="PROD" name="test"><label>PROD</label>
            <input type="radio" value="TEST" name="test"><label>TEST</label>
        </div>

        <div id="link"></div>
</div>
    <div id="elenco">
      <div class="cliente" value="PROD">
        cliente
        <div class="desc">
          scommettendo prod <br>
          <img src="">

        </div>
        <div class="funzioni">
          INDIRIZZI IP
          <button type="button" onclick="managerScomP(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('manager'))" id="m1">manager</button>
          <button type="button" onclick="reloadmemScommP(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('reload'), 'resultScommP')" id="r1">reload</button>
          <br>

          <ul>
            <li><button type="button" onclick="UpVersioneT(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('versione')+'/upgradeVersion','upVersionScommP')" class="rs1">UpVersione</button>
              <div class="resultVersion" id="upVersionScommP">Risultato</div>
            </li>
            <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('reload')[0]+'/contogiocoReload','resultScommP0')" class="rs1"></button>
              <div class="result" id="resultScommP0">Risultato</div>
            </li>
            <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('reload')[1]+'/contogiocoReload','resultScommP1')" class="rs1"></button>
              <div class="result" id="resultScommP1">Risultato</div>
            </li>
            <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('reload')[2]+'/contogiocoReload','resultScommP2')" class="rs1"></button>
              <div class="result" id="resultScommP2">Risultato</div>
            </li>

          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cliente" value="TEST">
        cliente
        <div class="desc">
          scommettendo test <br>
          <img src="">

        </div>
        <div class="funzioni">
          INDIRIZZI IP
          <button type="button" onclick="managerScomP(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo test').get('manager'))" id="m1">manager</button>
          <button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo test').get('reload')[0]+'/XContogioco/contogiocoReload', 'resultScommT0')" id="r1">reload</button>
          <br>

          <ul>
            <li><button type="button" onclick="UpVersioneT(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo test').get('versione')+'/XContogioco/upgradeVersion','UpVersionScommT0')" class="rs1">UpVersione</button>
              <div class="resultVersion" id="UpVersionScommT0">Risultato</div>
            </li>
            <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo test').get('reload')[0]+'/XContogioco/contogiocoReload', 'resultScommT0')" class="rs1"></button>
              <div class="result" id="resultScommT0">Risultato</div>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cliente" value="PROD">
        cliente
        <div class="desc">
          bgame prod <br>
          <img src="">

        </div>
        <div class="funzioni">
          INDIRIZZI IP

          <button type="button" onclick="managerScomP(clienti.get('bgame').get('bgame prod').get('manager'))" id="m1">manager</button>
          <button type="button" onclick="reloadmemScommP(clienti.get('bgame').get('bgame prod').get('reload'), 'resultBgameP')" id="r1">reload</button>
          <br>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <button type="button" onclick="UpVersioneT(clienti.get('bgame').get('bgame prod').get('versione') + '/upgradeVersion','UpVersioneBP')" class="rs1">UpVersione</button>
              <div class="resultVersion" id="UpVersioneBP">Risultato</div>
            </li>
            <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('bgame').get('bgame prod').get('reload')[0] +'/contogiocoReload','resultBgameP0')" class="rs1"></button>
              <div class="result" id="resultBgameP0">Risultato</div>
            </li>
            <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('bgame').get('bgame prod').get('reload')[1] +'/contogiocoReload','resultBgameP1')" class="rs1"></button>
              <div class="result" id="resultBgameP1">Risultato</div>
            </li>
            <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('bgame').get('bgame prod').get('reload')[2] +'/contogiocoReload','resultBgameP2')" class="rs1"></button>
              <div class="result" id="resultBgameP2">Risultato</div>
            </li>
            <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('bgame').get('bgame prod').get('reload')[3] +'/contogiocoReload','resultBgameP3')" class="rs1"></button>
              <div class="result" id="resultBgameP3">Risultato</div>
            </li>

          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

solution

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sito").on("keyup", function() {
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      //console.log(this)
      $("#elenco .cliente .desc").filter(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        

      });
    });
});
```

Comment: And..... where's the error/issue? Please give us more clues, like an [mcve]

Comment: the question is how can i make this become dynamic? In the sense that the div element is automatically found, like when you search on google, a list of probable searches appears below. You must do this as I type. Only the divs relating to those specific characters entered should begin to appear.

Comment: So update your question with this information, and show what you have tried to make this dynamic.

Comment: i updated my question with proof of the filter working incorrectly, as i say in the text it has to search the searched text only in the desc section of the div elements but then it has to hide the div element in full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sito").on("keyup", function() {
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      //console.log(this)
      $("#elenco .cliente .desc").filter(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        

      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.